# PostgreSQL Save and Pick files as large objects with C libpq

Tags: c, postgresql, blob, libpq

I am working in this issue since 2 weeks without any result. Do someone know how to manage with lipq with blobs or bytea without losing format and any data? The exported file size is 0B, I can not understand the steps I must follow to upload a file to a postgreSQL database from C and pick it again with the correct format and features. Any help will be great. I tryed near every example and theory on the net, even PG documents and manuals, no way. I am close to quit programing and go farmer (not jocking xD). Thank you in advance.

*<CODE EDITED mantaining transaction open 24-5-21>*

After code modifications, I pick a file 59bytes higher than the file uploaded as large object. Feeling I am closer but changing my mind about using Large Objects.

```
#include "libpq/libpq-fs.h"
#include "libpq-fe.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //*************************** IMPORT TEST **********
    manager.conn = manager.ConnectDB();  // my manager, working fine    

    Oid blob;
    char* picName = new char[]{ "powerup.png" };
    PGresult* res;

    ress = PQexec(manager.conn, "begin");
    PQclear(res);

    blob = lo_import(manager.conn, "powerup.png");
    cout << endl << "import returned oid " << blob;

    //res = PQexec(manager.conn, "end");
    //PQclear(res);

    string sentenceB = "INSERT INTO testblob(filename, fileoid) VALUES('powerup.png', '" + std::to_string(blob) + "')";

    manager.GenericQuery(manager.conn, sentenceB); //same as PQexec + result evaluation, works ok
    PQclear(res);

    //*************************** EXPORT TEST **********

    OidManager oidm;

    oidm.exportFile(manager.conn, blob, picName);  // Ill show the function content at the end

    res = PQexec(manager.conn, "end"); //SAME TRANSACTION TO AVOID LOSING THE OID, CHANGES AFTER TRANSACTION...
    PQclear(res);

    manager.CloseConn(manager.conn);   // my manager, works fine

    return true;
}

    // oidm.exportFile() FUNCTION DETAIL
    // code from: 35.5 Example Program Chapter 34 Large Objects
    // https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/lo-examplesect.html

void OidManager::exportFile(PGconn* conn, Oid lobjId, char* filename)
{
    int         lobj_fd;
    char        buf[BUFSIZE];
    int         nbytes,
        tmp;
    int         fd;

    /*
     * open the large object
     */
    lobj_fd = lo_open(conn, lobjId, INV_READ);
    if (lobj_fd < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open large object %u", lobjId);

    /*
     * open the file to be written to
     */
    fd = _open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (fd < 0)
    {                           /* error */
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open unix file\"%s\"",
            filename);
    }

    /*
     * read in from the inversion file and write to the Unix file
     */
    while ((nbytes = lo_read(conn, lobj_fd, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        tmp = _write(fd, buf, nbytes);
        if (tmp < nbytes)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error while writing \"%s\"",
                filename);
        }
    }

    lo_close(conn, lobj_fd);
    _close(fd);

    return;
}
```

Comment: You can find the solution to the recomendation done by @Laurenz Albe avoiding to use BLOBS and doing the job with BYTEA database slot type at this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673603/postgresql-save-and-pick-files-using-bytea-binary-data-with-c-libpq Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-interfaces.html#LO-OPEN) says:

> The descriptor is only valid for the duration of the current transaction.

So you must call `lo_open` and `lo_read` in the same transaction.

Do not use large objects. [They are slow](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/binary-data-performance-in-postgresql/), complicated to use and give you all kinds of serious trouble (for example, [if you have many of them](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/ed7d86a1-b907-4f53-9f6e-63482d2f2bac%40manitou-mail.org#aabfdd97d56a689237df4750974de785)). Use `bytea`, then your code will become much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for the answer, I remember I have readed some of your posts before :) I tryed in a minut to close the transaction after the exportFile(). This time the size of the exported file is 59 bytes higher ._.' and unable to be recognized as an image. I have to leave the office but I will check this as the first thing tomorrow.

Comment: In case I succed picking the file with the correct binary data working correctly I will have to investigate how to find mi oids if the saved ID's are not the same that I store in the 'testblob' table after end transactions.

I have worked a lot before, trying to do this with a table with a bytea slot with raw bytes without succed. I will prepare a piece of code showing what I was trying to do with the bytea Issue tomorrow. I hope understand what I am doing bad before to get fired xDDD

Comment: I will study all your links before posting my bytea atempts. Thanks again @Laurenz Albe ;)